# Steam runs slowly on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: games, steam

I just get rid of Windows and installed Ubuntu on my PC as main OS. I heard Linux gaming doesn't suck anymore. I tried to play some games that I've bought when I had Windows, so I installed Steam from the software center and it's running super slowly. I do have the hardware to play and have a nice gaming experience since in Windows I never had any problems.

I already tried reinstalling Ubuntu but it's still the same. Do I have to install certain driver or something?

Comment: Look for other "*steam is slow*" questions. See what kinds of information those folks had to provide and how to obtain that information. Add that information about your system to your Question above.

Answer (score 0):

I have games faster on Ubuntu 21.04 than on Windows 10.

- Problems with online games?
- use nvidia?
- if so, disable nvidia control panel Sync to VBlank, and the image settings High Performance must be set.